# Pseudo code example of call-by-value-result

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing

What would this C-like psuedo-code return for the following code. In this code assume the parameters for `incrementAll` are using call-by-value-result. Thanks for any help.

```
void incrementAll (int val1, int val2, int val3) {
  val1 += 1;
  val2 += 1;
  val3 += 1;
}
void main() {
  int save = 1;
  int list[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  incrementAll(save, list[save], list[list[save]]);
   for (int i=0; i < listLength; i++) {
            printf("%d ", list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about what you want to ask here. if you are talking about that the main will return, it won't return anything, function won't return anything. can you clear my confusion?

Comment: Sorry I updated main. Main should now print the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Call be value result, the output would be 13445, as in call by value result, first the array value will be copied to the local variables, at the end of function call, the changed value is copied back into the original parameters. But it is not a feature of C.

Comment: this is supposed to be hypothetical not literal C code. I'm saying we assume that incrementAll is call by value result. Sorry for not making that clearer.

Comment: @DanielKobe If it is a hypothetical C code, the code will still return 12345 as long as it is call by value, unless I am not able to get the question, sorry

Comment: No its not call by value, its call by value-result

Comment: @DanielKobe Oh sorry, then the output would be 13445, as in call by value result, first the array value will be copied to the local variables, at the end of function call,  the changed value is copied back into the original parameters. But it is not a feature of C.

Comment: Cool. This is the answer I got as well. If you update your answer I can select it.